# DatetimePicker sort C#

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have two DateTimePicker control on my win form...and all i want is when the user select the  datetimepicker(from: ) and ( To: ) the datagridview shows the selected date and year that the user selected..........here's my code.... i need the sort thing

P.S: i used STORED PROCEDURE

```
public void period()
{
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_insertcategory";
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            int n = metroGrid1.Rows.Add();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = rdr[0].ToString();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = rdr[1].ToString();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = rdr[2].ToString();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = rdr[3].ToString();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = rdr[4].ToString();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = rdr[5].ToString();
            metroGrid1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = rdr[6].ToString();
        }
     }
     cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning....... and i'm new to this

Comment: You need to pass dates as parameters to your stored procedure. Search about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same from SQL query (In your case stored procedure itself). Just add below syntax in your SQL query to sort the data in descending order..

```
ORDER BY post_datetime DESC //post_datetime is columnName which contains DateTime
```

`ASC` can be used if you need sorting in ascending order.

Details about `order by` can be found at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp